# how to see if all checkboxes are empty in php

Tags: php, wordpress

In PHP, how do I see if all checkboxes are empty? This is an excerpt from my code:
Basically, I want to use an "if" and "else" code that is specifically for when all my checkboxes are unchecked.

```
$titlebox=isset($_GET['title']) ? "checked='checked'" : '';
$authorbox=isset($_GET['author']) ? "checked='checked'" : '';

// keeps checkboxes checked after submit

<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
<input type="checkbox" name="title" '.$titlebox.' >
    <label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="author" '.$authorbox.' >
    <label for="author">Author</label>
</form>

// form

if (isset($_GET['title']))
    { $searchbooktitle = $bookfieldtitle; 
    }
    else
    { $searchbooktitle = NULL;
    };

// this is how I get individual checkboxes.
```

The last part shows how I get individual checkboxes, but how do I get all the checkboxes and see if they are empty? I'd like to use a specific "if" and "else" code that will strictly apply only if all checkboxes are unchecked.

The answer might be simple but I'm new at this and confused. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the code below which works perfectly fine without the need of having to rewrite my form and any of my other codes.

```
if ((!isset($_GET['title'])) && (!isset($_GET['author'])) && (!isset($_GET['series'])) && (!isset($_GET['year'])) && (!isset($_GET['isbn'])) && (!isset($_GET['tags'])) && (!isset($_GET['description'])))
    { $searchbookdefault = $bookfieldtitle; 
    }
    else
    { $searchbookdefault = NULL;
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can post checkboxes as array using this syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="title"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="author"/>
```

And in your PHP:

```
if (count($_GET['data']) == 0) {
    // nothing set
} else {
    // something is set
    if (in_array('author', $_GET['data']) {
        //author is selected
    } 
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: I did what you advised but now I'm getting
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

This is what my code looks like based from your advice:
http://pastebin.com/da2mTc8K

Comment: You forgot to add `[]` to end of your "name" attribute. Change `name="cbox"` to `name="cbox[]"` and everything should work now :)

Comment: Oops, i forgot to type it at pastebin but please believe me when i say that `[]` was in my code. The search form works fine if I search for something: `mysite.com/?type=books&search=jane&cbox[]=author` The warning only appears when no search is made, it appears at `mysite.com/` and if when no checkboxes are checked upon submit. I am using `if (count($_GET['cbox']) == 0)
 { $searchbookdefault = $bookfieldtitle; 
    }
 else
    { $searchbookdefault = NULL;
    };` But even without it, the warning still appears. :(

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
<form name="search_field" id="search_field" action="formpage.php" method="post" >
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  />
    </form>
```

You can get the working result from this (For your better understanding):

```
<form name="search_field" id="search_field" action="formpage.php" method="post" >
 <?php if(!$_POST == ''){ ?>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("mon", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("tue", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("wed", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("thr", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("fri", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("sat", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("sun", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<?php } else { ?>


 <form name="search_field" id="search_field" action="formpage.php" method="post" >
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>



<?php } ?>
```

Just create the formpage.php file, paste the above code and check the result.